# .htaccess redirect stripping slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just can't figure it out. My .htaccess rules look like follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|de)(/.*)?$ $2?lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

My plan obviously is to redirect as follows:

- http://example.com/whatever/goes/here => https://example.com/whatever/goes/here
- http://example.com/ => https://example.com/
- http://www.example.com/example => https://example.com/example
- https://www.example.com/ => https://example.com/
- and append all the /en or /de request uris as query string ?lang=de|en

So the last rule works like expected. The weired behaviour is that requests to `http://www.example.com/test` or `http://example.com/test` get redirected to `https://example.comtest`. It looks like the slash of the rule  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1` between `%{SERVER_NAME}` and the request uri `$1` is just not added.

Would be so happy if somebody could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

## remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(en|de)(/.*)?$ $2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.